# Unable to create Guest Admin in test on Trailhead Module

Tags: admin

Challenge not yet complete in My Trailhead Playground 1

An inactive user with 'guestadmin' in the username was not found. Make sure that the user is inactive and that the Username includes the 'guestadmin' string

Comment: What is your question? Did you encounter an error when you tried to complete the requirements for the module? It sounds like the validation checker is telling you you've missed something.

Comment: it show me an error that the username is already exist but i dont have this username.

Challenge Requirements
Create a new user with the following settings:
Profile: System Administrator
User License: Salesforce
Username: Must include guestadmin somewhere in it
The new user must be inactive

Answer (score 1):

Usernames are required to be globally unique in Salesforce, not just across your org. You need to come up with a unique user name (perhaps include your name and a random number) that also meets Trailhead's requirements.

That's why Trailhead asks that your username *contain* the string "guestadmin". You will need to find a username that is available.

Comment: i can't find it , So if i want to recreate this username. how can i delete previous one?

Comment: @RizwanAli Salesforce users cannot be deleted. You'll need to create a new user.

Comment: OK  I am trying this